# Calling php file from form

Tags: php, html, forms

I have an HTML form that I need to call a php script upon pressing submit but can't work out why the script isn't being executed.

```
<form action="update.php" method="POST">    

<input name="id"  type="hidden" value="id"/>
<input name="subArea"       type="text"     placeholder="Sub Area (optional)"/>     
<label><textarea name="description" rows="2" cols="80" placeholder="Description" ></textarea></label>   
<label><input type="radio" name="markNA[]" value ="markNA"/> N/A? </label>

<input class = "btn-testname" type="submit" value="Change" name="update"/> 
</form >
```

I don't need the page to reload when pressing the button (so want to avoid Ajax) It was my understanding  that the method above will execute the script?

update.php

```
<?php
include ("databaseLogin.php");

// Create connection to Database
$con = mysqli_connect('localhost',$dbuser,$dbpass,$dbname);

if (!$con) 
{
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}

// Sql Query
$sql = "INSERT INTO `table_tests` (`active`, `description`) 
        VALUES (1, 'newstuff')";

mysqli_query($con, $sql);
?>
```

EDIT 1: I excluded the bringing in of the POST vars just to simplify the php code (and hard coded them into the sql query)

If I'm just missing a stupid syntax error I apologise.

Comment: Works fine for me! Please describe more what you mean with: `script isn't being executed` Also show the code from the script

Comment: The code shown would send a POST request to update.php where PHP code should process it. If this is intended it should work fine. However I cannot tell what you're trying to do...

Comment: have you made the form called update.php and not accidently called  it with html extension. try an print_r with the POST vars at the top of update

Comment: your not bringing in your post vars, $dbuser,$dbpass,$dbname will all be empty. try adding $dbuser=S_POST['id']; etc to carry your post vars across

Comment: Sorry I excluded the bringing in of the post vars and hard coded them in for this question.  but regardless of that, the vars you speak about are included in the first line of the php file

Comment: not the way you have it now they're not....

Answer (score 0):

You have to reload the page or atleast go to another page, PHP is a server sided language so it cant make realtime changes. if you want to do that you have to use javascript.

but the way you are using now you can get the variables from this page in `update.php`:

```
$description = $_POST["description"];
```

If you have that code on `update.php` the text filled in the description textbox will be saved as the variable `$description` so you can validate forms for example

======================

## EDIT

To get the values of for example the textbox 'description' you can use:

```
document.getElementById("searchTxt").value;
```

So if you want to get it on a button click you do :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function check () {
        document.getElementById("description").value;
    }
</script>
<button onclick="check()"></button>
```

Here you get the value of the field where `ID="description"`
There are ways you can get it by name but I always rather use ID

```
 document.getElementsByName('description')[0].value
```

the code above gives you the first element with the name description

Comment: How would I set up the form so that it calls a javascript function and gets the values of the form into the function?

Answer (score 0):

```
**Try this**


<form action="update.php" method="POST">    

    <input name="id"  type="hidden" value="id"/>
    <input name="subArea"       type="text"     placeholder="Sub Area (optional)"/>     
    <label><textarea name="description" rows="2" cols="80" placeholder="Description" ></textarea></label>   
    <label><input type="radio" name="markNA" value ="markNA"/> N/A? </label>

    <input class = "btn-testname" type="submit" value="Change" name="update"/> 
    </form >


    <?php
    include ("databaseLogin.php");

    // Create connection to Database
    $con = mysqli_connect('localhost',$dbuser,$dbpass,$dbname);

    if (!$con) 
    {
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($con));
    }
    $description = $_POST['description'];
    $active= $_POST['markNA'];
$id= $_POST['id'];
    // Sql Query
    $sql = "INSERT INTO `table_tests` (`active`, `description`,`id`) 
            VALUES ('$active', '$description','$id')";

    mysqli_query($con, $sql);
    ?>
```

Comment: Do not use raw user data in your queries!

Comment: Yeah, user data should be checked before entering into an sql db.  also, why would your answer produce anthing different.  All I have done in my example is hard code the values into sql query to see whether the php file is being called (which it appears not to be)